# How to get the API/Web Service(Rest or SOAP)?

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, integration, query

How to get or list the API\ Web Service(Rest or SOAP)  in Salesforce org ?
I am using UL edition , and there are many packages installed, So I need make documents kind of report or list the available  API\ Web Service(Rest or SOAP) both in and out.

Is there simple way to  query or any free tool(workbench) will help me this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SOSL for this requirement. A basic search would just be to look for any `ApexClass` containing the relevant keywords. Here is a sample script:

```
Set<String> inbound = new Set<String>();
for (List<SObject> result : [
    FIND '@RestResource OR webservice' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass (Name)
]) for (SObject record : result) inbound.add((String)record.get('Name'));

Set<String> outbound = new Set<String>();
for (List<SObject> result : [
    FIND 'Http()' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass (Name)
]) for (SObject record : result) outbound.add((String)record.get('Name'));
```

Or, if terse isn't your thing, here is a more verbose version:

```
Set<String> inbound = new Set<String>();
List<List<SObject> results = [
    FIND '@RestResource OR webservice' IN ALL FIELDS
    RETURNING ApexClass (Name)
];
for (List<SObject> result : results)
{
    for (SObject record : result)
    {
        inbound.add((String)record.get('Name'));
    }
}

Set<String> outbound = new Set<String>();
List<List<SObject> results = [
    FIND 'Http()' IN ALL FIELDS
    RETURNING ApexClass (Name)
];
for (List<SObject> result : results)
{
    for (SObject record : result)
    {
        outbound.add((String)record.get('Name'));
    }
}
```

Of course, well versed developers may write ***utility classes*** which make callouts, so you may need to broaden your search based on the initial results.